# Is it possible to write a custom annotator when using Stanford CoreNLP through C#?

Tags: c#, stanford-nlp

I am using the NuGet version of stanford corenlp version 3.9.1.  I can create and use a standard pipeline just fine.  However, I have written a couple of custom pipeline annotators in Java, one of which I also wrote the C# equivalent for so I have both Java and C# implementations laying around.  I wish to do like

```
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, custom.ner");
```

where custom.ner could be either C# or Java code.  When using the C# version I get:

> Result StackTrace:     at Java_java_lang_Class.forName0(String name,
>   Boolean initialize, ClassLoader loader, Class caller)    at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(String className, CallerID )    at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass.ClassFactory.construct(String ,
>   Class[] )    at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass.ClassFactory..ctor(String , Object[] )
>   at edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass.ClassFactory..ctor(String ,
>   Object[] , 1 )    at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass.createFactory(Object[] objects)  ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass.createFactory(Object[] objects)    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass.createInstance(Object[] objects)
>   at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.custom(Properties
>   properties, String property)    at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$null$67(AnnotatorImplementations
>   , Properties , String )    at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.__<>Anon39.get()    at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy.3.compute()    at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy.get()    at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(String name)    at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(Properties ,
>   Boolean , AnnotatorImplementations )    at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP..ctor(Properties props,
>   Boolean enforceRequirements, AnnotatorPool annotatorPool)    at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP..ctor(Properties props,
>   Boolean enforceRequirements)    at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP..ctor(Properties props)
>   at MyPath.NerScoringTests.Initialize() in
>   MyPath\NerScoringTests.cs:line 139 Result Message:    Initialization
>   method MyPath.NerScoringTests.Initialize threw exception.
>   edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass+ClassCreationException:
>   edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass+ClassCreationException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyPath.Annotators.NERAnnotator --->
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyPath.Annotators.NERAnnotator.

How could I hook this up so that MetaClass will be able to find my custom annotator class?